# Selenium python, how to get element position after scrolling way down the page?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page with multiple elements in a grid that I want to get their position. The idea is to go row by row and get the position, and scroll down if it reaches the bottom row that is visible on the screen. The problem is when I get the position with element.location, it gets the absolute Y position in the whole page, not the position on screen.

How do I get the Y position relative to the screen?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your particular case you have not to read the relative Y position of the element.
Instead of this you can keep the previous Y position and compare it with the new Y position.
When scrolled till the end, scrolling again will no more change the Y position of the element so the previous Y position will stay equal to the new Y element position.